# .htaccess redirect a fake directory to an actual directory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've seen many examples of  using .htaccess, but I couldn't find this one. I am currently using WHMCS, and I want to be able to have a fake admin directory to use as a decoy, but as soon as the system recognizes that there is an admin directory, it will no longer let me access the actual administrator directory. (Ensuring a user properly upgraded).

I am trying to make a rule that will redirect something like example.com/admin to example.com/fakeadmin, where fakeadmin is the real directory. So far, I did:

```
RewriteRule ^admin$  /fakeadmin/$1 [L,NC]
```

This works if I access example.com/admin, but I need it so that it would work for example.com/admin/folder1, and so on.

Basically, creating a fake "duplicate" of a directory with htaccess.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have the `$1` in your rule but you aren't using a capture group, so that won't do anything. You are basically just telling it to only match on `admin`. You can do something like this.

```
RewriteRule ^admin/?(.*)/?$  /fakeadmin/$1 [L,NC]
```